# Why does the NetworkX generate an adjacency matrix that is not symmetric for an undirected graph

Tags: python, matrix, graph, networkx, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to learn coding using NetworkX. I am now trying to get the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph using following code I wrote:

```
mat = nx.adjacency_matrix(graph)
matDense = mat.todense();

print(len(matDense ))
print(len(matDense [0]))
```

The output is

```
38
1
```

My understanding for adjacency matrix is that it should be symmetric, however, the output seems like not, seems like the adjacency matrix generated by NetworkX is an 38*1 matrix instead of 38*38?

If this, how may I access individual cells of an adjacency matrix, currently I could only locate to rows.If matDense[0][2], an array index out of bounds error will be thrown.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a square matrix.

The problem is in this command:

```
print(len(matDense [0]))
```

`matDense[0]` is a matrix consisting of a single row.  The `len` command in this case is telling you there is just one row.  Try

```
print(len(matDense[0].transpose()))
```